# Querying MongoDB to match in the first item in an array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm aware of the `$in` operator, which appears to search for an item's presence in array, but I only want to find a match if the item is in the first position in an array.

For instance:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("0"),
    "imgs" : [
        "http://foo.jpg",
        "http://bar.jpg",
        "http://moo.jpg",
        ]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("1"),
    "imgs" : [
        "http://bar.jpg",
        "http://foo.jpg",
        "http://moo.jpg",
        ]
}
```

I'm looking for a query akin to:

```
db.products.find({"imgs[0]": "http://foo.jpg"})
```

This would/should return the `ObjectId("0")` but not `ObjectId("1")`, as it's only checking against the first image in the array.

How can this be achieved? I'm aware I could just create a separate field which contains a single string for `firstImg` but that's not really what I'm after here.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

I believe you want `imgs.0`. eg, given your example document, you want to say: `db.products.find({"imgs.0": "http://foo.jpg"})`

Be aware that referencing array indexes only works for the first-level array. Mongo doesn't support searching array indexes any deeper.

Comment: Great. By first-level array do you mean that it won't work on arrays within arrays/arrays within objects>

Comment: The following would not work:

`{"images.0.5": "foo.jpg"}`
`{"images.0.aliases.3": "foo.jpg"}`

The following will work:

`{"images.2.name": "foo.jpg"}`

That is, multiple levels of nesting work, but only one level of "array-indexing" is supported by Mongo.

Comment: do you have any reference for the "only first-level array" part?

Comment: At least on MongoDB version 3.2.6, there is no problem with nested indices. 
i.e. on the document: `{a: [{b: [1,2]}, [3,4]]}`, the query `db.testcollection.find({"a.0.b.1": 1})` works correctly.

Comment: See also: [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#op._S_elemMatch): `db.products.find({"imgs": {$elemMatch: {"0": "http://foo.jpg"}}})`

Comment: @Udi, do you know if that usage is deprecated for v4.2? I couldn't get it to work

Answer (score 16):

You can use dot notation for array indexes:

```
db.products.find({"imgs.0": "http://foo.jpg"})
```

Here is an excerpt from the relevant documentation for [dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation).

> MongoDB uses the dot notation to access the elements of an array and to access the fields of a subdocument.
>
> To access an element of an array by the zero-based index position, concatenate the array name with the dot (.) and zero-based index position, and enclose in quotes:
>
> `'<array>.<index>'`

Additionally, here is a link to the relevant [array documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#read-operations-arrays).